# How to edit the default database of WordPress

Tags: php, plugin-development, theme-development, database, mysql

How do I create a complete organisation's database, where I can access tables and perform custom SQL requests.
I can use PHP and mySQL, I am actually working on a WordPress theme.
And I am trying to do something like this:

```
+----------+     +------------+     +------------+
| Book     |     | Borrow     |     | Reader     |
|----------|     |------------|     |------------|
|codeBook# |_____|codeBook#   |     |codeReader# |
|title     |     |codeReader# |_____|name        |
|datepub   |     |date        |     |age         |
+----------+     +------------+     |contacts    |
                                    +------------+
```

Some explanation and link will be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that accessing the [phpmyadmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) dashboard of your host, but that is no the right way to do it, i recommend you to research and learn about:

- [Custom Post Types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types)
- [Custom Taxonomies](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies)

Comment: Thanks @David for the hints, I have posted an answer, because it was too big for a comment

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

- I have already created `custom post type` for different needs(eg. Book and Reader).
- I will manually create the remaining tables(eg. Borrow) in phpMyAdmin
- Then use comment `$wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT....');` for custom query

Comment: It's better to use built-in functionality. In this case, set up Borrow as a custom taxonomy. Then you're not adding non-WP tables and running custom queries.